# Human friendly Unique URL

Tags: java, php, url-rewriting, url-routing, redirect

So we have this "bloggish" site for which we are building a `better URL scheme`. The basic idea is to convert the URLs to a `human and SEO friendly structure`. I have a function which generates the `URL slug` based on the title of the posting.

A record looks kind of like this in the database now:

```
    post_id         post_title              post_url_slug
--------------------------------------------------------------       
    1               Hello World             hello-world
    2               Another Post            another-post
```

So now we can change

`http://<site>/post.cgi?action=read&id=1`

to `http://<site>/post/read/hello-world`

In order to ensure that the url is unique, we are planning to append the post_id to it.

So now `http://<site>/post/read/hello-world`

becomes `http://<site>/post/read/hello-world-1`

All of this works very well. My main question is how should we handle the situation if the blog poster edits his title? We wouldn't want `hello-world-1` to be showing a totally unrelated post.

The obvious solution is to recreate the slug when the title is edited. But how will we handle user `bookmarks/google tracking/SEO crawling`? We could do a `301 redirect`, but keeping a whole history of URL slug changes and redirecting them like that can quickly become unmanageable.

Also I would really prefer keeping the routing/rewriting/redirections within the application and not a custom on the fly .htaccess or something. The reason being that if it is in the application and something goes wrong only some users will have issues, but we all know what happens when files like `.htaccess` catches fire!

Does anyone have any insight/experience managing such scenario? Any inputs are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the pages are being created dynamically based on the URL, in particular the id.  In which case, why not have the page id as its own segment, ie

http:///post/read/1/hello-world

You could then either allow http:///post/read/1/another-hello-world to show the same page, or make it so that your router checks that the id matches the title, and if it does not, it redirects to the correct URL.

If **every** wrong title redirects to the right URL then you would not have to keep a history of changes.

Unless it is unique, the title should not be being used to say what content to show, the unique id should.

You could also do the 
http:///post/read/hello-world-1
method by casting "hello-world-1" as an integer to retrieve the "1".  That would mean you would have to filter numbers from the page title, however, and I personally think it looks a messier URL.

EDIT: I suspect this is what Stack Overflow are doing
stackoverflow.com/questions/24637589/helloworld
redirects to this page - they just need the "24637589" to know what page and url to show.

Comment: I hear what you say. I had researched the SO URLs as well :) It is a bit different than you explained because for some urls if you edit `stackoverflow.com/questions/24637589/hello-world ` it will take you to `stackoverflow.com/questions/24637234/new-id-and-slug `

Comment: In any case the reason why we didnt want to do `id/url-title` was because of crawlers marking duplicates... if url-title is not a required part, then there is point in having it in the url in the first place - people will start omitting it, or having obsolete ones - everything will work, but will confuse the sh!t out of users and crawlers alike!

Comment: It could be required - redirect id/ to id/url-title - you validate that the right url has been entered, as SO are doing.

Comment: You have any examples of the URLs that redirect to a new id? I assume they are probably ones where questions have been combined or moved by moderators.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer that you already know and won't like is that you have to keep track of slug changes and modify your app to respond accordingly if you want to keep your current URL scheme untouched. There's really no other way to keep "old" slugs active outside of keeping track of them in some fashion and adding them to your routing table. I would suggest keeping "old" slugs in a separate store which is designed specifically for this purpose so you can route them efficiently. You could then create somewhat efficient routing logic which says "Is this slug recognized? Yes => Route, No => Is this an old slug? Yes => Route, No => Slug not found.